# Fragmented UTC file

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet, keystore

I recovered my deleted UTC keystore file from 2018 using Recovery Software. The File is fragmented. It looks like this:

[image: Fragmented UTC file]

Is there any way i can defragmentate the file?